# How can I exclude required fields in a validation script?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to create a multi step form with validation based on required fields.
The current Javascript I'm using is just looking for fields that are filled in to validate the form. But how do I make it ignore fields that are not marked as "required" in the html?

Thank you!

```
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false:
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

Comment: You're going to make a lot of enemies with those one-letter variable names. Just don't.

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I make it ignore fields that are not marked as "required" in the html?

The following solution checks for the `required` property in the `input` elements. So in the `for` loop, the first thing you would do is `if(!y[i].required){ continue; }`, in other words if `y[i].required` is `undefined`, then `continue` (or skip this iteration).

```
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // --> if y[i].required is undefined... skip to the next <--
    if(!y[i].required){ continue; }
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false:
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add in some text to explain what problems you found in the OP's code and how your answer fixes or addresses those problems.

Comment: This worked! Thank you!!  I just didn't know how to called the required attribute since it wasn't a class.  So it's considered a tag?

Comment: @JeepGirl - it's considered an attribute of the tag / element

Comment: If the provided solution meets your requirements, please remember to mark it as accepted answer.